# Job Site Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion

Inspired by this question: [Are there any good job directories for academic work?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/are-there-any-good-job-directories-for-academic-work)

This question has a number of very specific answers based on field - and while general answers like "Check Science and Nature" or look for a field specific society are helpful, there's a distinct possibility that fields will have little hidden sources - listservs, a particular newsletter, etc.

This seems like the kind of thing a Community Wiki is well suited for. Thoughts?